# What are equivalents for Windows 7 Phone PhoneCallTask, EmailCompmoseTask, and BingMapsTask in Blackberry Cascades

Tags: qt, windows-phone-7, qml, email-client, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to find equivalents for Windows 7 Phone PhoneCallTask, EmailComposeTask, and BingMapsTasks in Blackberry Cascades Beta 3 SDK - I found one for the PhoneCallTask which is (bb::system::phone::Phone phone) - which has a function called requestDialpad, which is supposed to bring up a dialpad, but it does not do that (I am using Blackbery 10 Dev Alpha Simulator) - so I was wondering how to fix that or if there is a better class for phone calls.  Also for EmailComposeTask - I haven't managed to find anything for that.  For BingMapsTasks - I am using a WebView for displaying a Bing map at the location I want - but it doesn't show the map (it's just black) - maybe that's an issue with the simulator - but I was wondering if there was something better for that too.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will want to use the invocation framework in order to bring up cards. However the documentation on this has not yet been fully released. You will however, want to check out the MapView sample app.